# Power iteration for generalized eigenvalue problem $Ax = \lambda B x$ where $A$ and $B$ are singular

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

Generalized eigenvalue problem can be reduced to eigenvalue problem $B^{-1} A x = \lambda x$ if $B$ is non-singular matrix. Then, the standard power iteration method can be applied.

How can I use the power iteration method to find the largest eigenvalue and eigenvector of pencil $(A, B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are singular? If it is not possible to use the power iteration method, which computationally efficient method can I use to find the largest eigenvector of pencil $(A, B)$?

Comment: Just to note: for symmetric (or self-adjoint) $A$ and $B$ the $B^{-1}A$ method is bad, since $B^{-1}A$ wouldn't in general be self-adjoint. This is usually solved using Cholesky decomposition $B=LL^T$ and solving $L^{-1}AL^{-T}x=\lambda x$, benefiting from $L^{-1}AL^{-T}$ being self-adjoint.

Comment: @lisyarus actually, for my problem $A=\sum_i^k u_k u_k^T$ is rank $k < n$ and $B = v v^T$ is a rank-one matrix.

Comment: Those look symmetric to me!

Comment: Before applying the numerical algorithm, what are the eigenpairs for your system $(A, B)$ (where $B$ is of rank 1)?

Comment: When B is symmetric positive definite, the power iteration is 1. pick $x_0$; 2 $y_k = B^{-1} A x_k$; 3. $x_{k+1} = y_k / \sqrt{ y_k^T B y_k }$; 4. go to Step 2 - if needed.

Comment: @user7440 $B$ is symmetric positive semi-definite, so the inverse can't be computed.

Comment: You might find this helpful: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1604.03930.pdf. Algorithm 1 in this paper only requires B to be positive semidefinite.

Comment: @kkcocoqq doesn't algorithm 1 in this reference assume B is strictly positive definite? If it's not then the sub-problem argmin(w^TBw - w^TAw_t) would be unbounded whenever Aw_t is not in the image of B, which I don't think there's anything preventing